# Solution - idfa class missing, GAIProperty and GAIHit of GoogleAnalytics in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-analytics-api

I was in problem with **GoogleAnalytics** from so many days with following **error/warning** :

> **idfa class missing, won't collect idfa**
>
> **CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'GAIProperty' for entity 'GAIProperty'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.**
>
> **CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'GAIHit' for entity 'GAIHit'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.**

GoogleAnalytics has been lunched its new version 3.10 on 5th nov14 with fixed with above problem.

Just follow the steps to remove above three types of warnings.

1.Download this file from newly updated GoogleAnalytics v3.10 which lunched on 5th Nov **libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a** and **libAdIdAccess.a**

2.Add this both files into your `Framworks`.

Run your build this will not show the above warnings.

Comment: If you are using cocoa pods for integrating GoogleAnalytics. Then just add the libAdIdAccess.a framework to collect the IDFA